# Gnuplot - count of same value at same coordinate

Tags: graph, syntax, plot, gnuplot, radius

How can I get the number (count) of the same value at same coordinate.

I have:

time  number

0:25  5

0:25  15

0:25  15

0:30  78

0:30  78

0:30  100

time at x axis

number at y axis

And I want to draw graph "with circle". And the radius of each circle is 3 * count of same values.

for example:

radius = 3 * x

0:25  15

0:25  15    => count = 2 => radius = 3 * 2 = 6

And I don't know, which commands do I have to use.

Comment: You can't do this directly, use an external tool to do the counting

Comment: And please delete your other, duplicate question

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this kind of processing in a sane way inside of gnuplot. Use an external tool to do the preprocessing for you. An example would be the command line tool `uniq` with the `-c` flag, which prefixes each line with the number of occcurrences.

To use a variable radius, use three columns in the `using` statement:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt '%H:%M'
radius = 60 # must be given in seconds
plot '< uniq -c file.txt' using 2:3:($1 * radius) with circles
```

Note, that I assumed that your time is given in the format hour:minute. The radius must be given in units of the first axis, i.e. in your case in seconds.